# Power Series Approach to Real Functions

Tags: real-analysis

I am currently reading a paper

http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1935-41-04/S0002-9904-1935-06049-5/S0002-9904-1935-06049-5.pdf

and from some research, it seems that the author and also Pringsheim studied real and complex functions from the power series approach of Weierstrass school.

Can someone elaborate on this and what are some 'other' approaches?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know enough about complex variables to answer this, other than to offer that perhaps the other approaches are based on the idea of being complex differentiable and on the validity of certain integral representations. However, as someone who often pursues old literature, I have a suggestion that I often follow. Get ahold of several standard textbooks on the subject from the date the paper was written to approximately 30-40 years before the date the paper was written and look at what they have to say. In the past (before 2000 or so), at least for me, this meant checking out volumes from a university library (when I was at a university) or travelling to a university (often staying in a hotel one or two nights, especially when the nearest university library over 100 miles away) and photocopying appropriate sections from such textbooks. However, now this can mostly be done from any location with internet access. Further below are some examples of the books I would probably look at if I studying what you are studying and I had questions similar to your questions.

One way to find out about the existence of such books is to scan over the book reviews in old volumes of Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. and Amer. Math. Monthly. These used to be on (U.S.) university library shelves, so you could just sit down in front of them, pull the volumes off the shelves one-by-one, and quickly look through their table of contents. However, in the past 10-15 years many libraries have moved these volumes to remote storage locations that make this no longer possible, but the Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. volumes are now freely available on the internet and JSTOR offers those of Amer. Math. Monthly (sufficiently old volumes are freely available). Another way to find out about such books (quicker, but you get less information about the books) is to do various searches in the [JFM site](http://www.emis.de/MATH/JFM/JFM.html). I got the list of books below by searching this site for "words in title" (not phrase option) for the words "functions", "complex", and "variable".

Andrew Russell Forsyth, [**Theory Of Functions Of A Complex Variable**](http://archive.org/details/theoryoffunction028777mbp) (1918) [Or see the [1893 edition](http://name.umdl.umich.edu/ACM1009.0001.001)]

James Pierpont, [**Functions of a Complex Variable**](http://archive.org/details/functionsacompl01piergoog) (1914)

Heinrich Durège, [**Elements of the Theory of Functions of a Complex Variable with Especial Reference to the Methods of Riemann**](http://archive.org/details/elementsoftheory00dureiala) (1896 English translation)

Thomas Scott Fiske, [**Functions of a Complex Variable**](http://archive.org/details/functionsofcompl00fiskuoft) (1907)

Heinrich Burkhardt, [**Theory of Functions of a Complex Variable**](http://archive.org/details/theoryfunctions00burkgoog) (1913 English translation)

Edgar Jerome Townsend, [**Functions Of A Complex Variable**](http://archive.org/details/functionsofacomp028597mbp) (1915)

Thomas Murray MacRobert, [**Functions of a Complex Variable**](http://archive.org/details/functionsofcompl00macruoft) (1917)